# How to delete login session of Digit?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, twitter-digits

I have installed Digit mobile verification in my app and when the user verifies his mobile number and comes back, the app works fine. Now if the user want to make a sign up process again, his session is automatically created. Since I'm using this to only verify user's mobile number and then continue with my own sign up process. How can I do that?
**I want to just Remove all sessions.**

Comment: Are you on Swift 2 or Swift 3?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu swift 3

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Digits.sharedInstance().logOut() i try this but this not work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Digits in my project with the same intent. I used to simply call

```
Digits.sharedInstance().logOut()
```

Right before calling the method for authentication. This used to start a fresh login flow.

Comment: i want to simply re- register device on digit

Comment: I am afraid the control for that is with the user themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method below before initialise.

```
Digits.sharedInstance().logOut()

let digits = Digits.sharedInstance()
```